# SQL query with more than 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing an exercise on ORACLE SQL.

Currently I got 3 tables.

```
Student values = "student_id ,name"

Subjects values = "subject_id, name"

Scores values = "score, student_id, subject_id"
```

I'm trying to retrieve the following information from my database.

Name of student, Name and id of the subject and finally the score that has the student_id "34560".

```
SELECT scores.score, 
       scores.subject_id, 
       student.name, 
       subject.subject_id, 
       subject.name
  FROM scores 
 INNER JOIN students 
   ON scores.student_id = '34560'
INNER JOIN subject
   ON /* and here's where i'm lost*/
```

Is there a way to put all together from the first part of the query where I call the list of students with student_id = "34560" and then query that list to see if it matches with the subject_id?

Comment: Like Zaynul Abadin Tuhin proposed in his answer it is generally a better idea to use WHERE statements to retrieve a single dataset out of a table. JOIN operations can combine tables giving you all the datasets the Cartesian product leaves you with (maybe somewhat filtered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in` operator for list of student id

```
    SELECT sc.score, sc.subject_id, 
   st.name, sb.subject_id, sb.name
        FROM scores sc
        INNER JOIN students  st
        ON sc.student_id = st.student_id
        INNER JOIN subject sb
        ON sc.subject_id=sb.subject_id    
      where sc.student_id in ('34560','add_anotherstudentid','add_anotherstudentid') //you can add multiple student id
```

Comment: I can't barely believe how fast you solved it. Thank you very, very much! This has been solved.

Comment: @AlexandroNavarro if it helps please accept my answer as a SO appreciation